# Removed softwares after update and installation of new packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I update my system `apt update` and I try to install a new package, some packages like MySql Workbench and PlayOnLinux are removed, I'm not removing these packages explicity and any dependencie, so how can I ' fix ' it ?

Ubuntu 17.10, I tried to install using `aptitude`, `apt`, `gnome-software` and `synaptic` but it's the same thing on all.

Comment: Please share more details. Are MySql Workbench and PlayOnLinux installed from .deb's or from source? Where are they installed (which directories/paths?) Do you see something in the output of `apt update` showing they were uninstalled? Can you show commands demonstrating it's installed before and no longer installed after your `apt` command? These would be helpful in diagnosing the issue you're describing...

Comment: Workbench it's a `.deb` and Play On Linux it's a ppa, `/usr/bin/mysql-workbench` ( Play On Linux I need to install again to get the path, so ... ). Nope, I just get this output [here](https://i.imgur.com/tPsAUWx.png). E.g, `apt install curl` ( Then the system tell me to to remove the packages that I mentioned )

Comment: Please also post the output of `apt install curl`, especially the part where it tells you that packages will be removed (preferably by editing your question and as a code block instead of screenshot). What happens when you try to `apt upgrade`?